# Два элемента с одинаковыми именами, но разными типами

Tags: xsd

[image: Общий вид xsd]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="package" type="typeA"/>
    <!-- тип typeA -->
    <xs:complexType name="typeA">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tag">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:restriction base="typeB">
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- тип typeB -->
    <xs:complexType name="typeB">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:time"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

[image: Схема]

Есть узлы с одинаковыми именами, но имеющие разный тип значений. В данном случае значения времени и строка. Как можно их описать? В complexType при данной записи идет ошибка, что мол два name одинаковых.

Comment: В предложенном виде и предопределенными типами нельзя. Можно, если объявить у элемента tag кастомный абстрактный тип и потом описать типы, которые его уточняют. Почти как в ООП, только в декларативном стиле. Вы же не можете указать два типа хранимых значений для одной переменной в <выберите язык>, можете только не указать тип совсем (если язык поддерживает такие конструкции) или указать какой-то общий тип, наследники которого являются допустимыми значениями, так же и тут.

Comment: В языках с динамической типизацией не сложно на одну переменную вешать несколько типов. В данном случае засада возникает из-за ситуации, что xml уже жестко задана в нескольких вариантах. И я попытался использовать xsd для ее описания, что в лоб не удается. Но в xsd 1.1 это можно делать, хотя и жутко хитро: через <xs:alternative> и <xs:key>. Также мы очень долго искали опенсорсный парсер 1.1